How to solve the Could not find function "glimpse" error
I run following code in R, however it says error. please help.
glimpse(RSCH8230_Project1_Data_Raw)


Error in glimpse(RSCH8230_Project1_Data_Raw) :
could not find function "glimpse"

I was excepting glimpse of my imported excel data

You need to install and load the dplyr package e.g. install.packages("dplyr") then run library(dplyr) then run glimpse().
